# Get user info like name, email Id etc from authentication token in .NET Backend Azure Mobile Service

Tags: c#, authentication, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile Service to add authentication to my Windows Store app. Following [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-universal-dotnet-get-started-users/) article from Mobile Services documentation I am able to get the UserId as well as `MobileServiceAuthenticationToken` (both for Google as well as Microsoft Account)

My question is how do I get user info like `name, email Id` etc. using `MobileServiceAuthenticationToken` in a `.NET` backend mobile service. I have gone through various articles explaining how this is done in `Javascript` Backend mobile service but couldn't find anything properly implemented in `C# + .NET` backend mobile service.

Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting user info using authentication token from .Net Backend Azure Mobile Service:

1. Setup your mobile service with authentication for different providers by visiting [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-universal-dotnet-get-started-users/) - I did this for Microsoft, Google and Facebook.
2. Add a new controller to the mobile service and add the following code:

public class UserInfoController : ApiController
    {
        public ApiServices Services { get; set; }

```
    [AuthorizeLevel(AuthorizationLevel.User)]
    public async Task<JObject> GetUserInfo()
    {
        //Get the current logged in user
        ServiceUser user = this.User as ServiceUser;
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This can only be called by authenticated clients");
        }

        //Get Identity Information for the current logged in user
        var identities = await user.GetIdentitiesAsync();
        var result = new JObject();

        //Check if the user has logged in using Facebook as Identity provider
        var fb = identities.OfType<FacebookCredentials>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (fb != null)
        {
            var accessToken = fb.AccessToken;
            result.Add("facebook", await GetProviderInfo("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + accessToken));
        }

        //Check if the user has logged in using Microsoft Identity provider
        var ms = identities.OfType<MicrosoftAccountCredentials>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (ms != null)
        {
            var accessToken = ms.AccessToken;
            result.Add("microsoft", await GetProviderInfo("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/?method=GET&access_token=" + accessToken));
        }

        //Check if the user has logged in using Google as Identity provider
        var google = identities.OfType<GoogleCredentials>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (google != null)
        {
            var accessToken = google.AccessToken;
            result.Add("google", await GetProviderInfo("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + accessToken));
        }

        return result;
    }

    private async Task<JToken> GetProviderInfo(string url)
    {
        var c = new HttpClient();
        var resp = await c.GetAsync(url);
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return JToken.Parse(await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
}
```

Once done publish the mobile service. The above code gets the identity information for the current logged in user and then depending upon which authentication provider user has chosen (Microsoft, Facebook or Google) it makes a call to that identity provider's user profile API and gets the user information.

3. Add the following code in the client application to make a call to GetUserInfo method in mobile service:

```
var user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);                  
var userInfo = await App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync("userInfo", HttpMethod.Get, null);
```

However this will bring only some basic user information like name, gender etc. if your application requires more than that you can request additional scopes during the login, by setting the MS_FacebookScope and MS_MicrosoftScope app settings in mobile service Configure Tab in azure portal.

You can get more detailed information on this from this [excellent article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-login-scopes-single-sign-on-new-asp-net-web-api-updates-to-the-azure-mobile-services-net-backend/)

Comment: i'm trying this, is there information how how to get twitter info?

Answer (score 7):

Facebook, Google doesn't return you user profile name, e-mail when authorizing. They are giving you `access token` that can be used for future requests.

You need to request for example to Facebook Graph API for `name, email` with your `MobileServiceAuthenticationToken`.

You can use this library for accessing to Facebook API:
https://facebookgraphapi.codeplex.com/

```
// MobileServiceAuthenticationToken <- your token
var facebook = new FacebookGraphAPI(MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);

// Get user profile data 
var user = facebook.GetObject("me", null);
Console.WriteLine(user["name"]);
```

Comment: I tried out Facebook Graphs API, but not I am getting System.Net exception. Here is my code: `MobileServiceUser user = await App.MobileService                        .LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);                    
                    var fb = new FacebookGraphAPI(user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
                    var fbuser = fb.GetObject("me", null);
                    string username = fbuser["name"].ToString();`                      My guess is Graphs API is not accepting the Authentication Token as I am getting error on fb.GetObject("me", null);

Comment: I am new to Stack overflow so figuring out the markdown... :) I have posted the code

Comment: Can you post exactly what exception you get ?

Comment: 'An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: Have you added `System.Web` to your project References ?

Comment: If I try to add `System.Web` reference explicitly I am getting an error that this component is automatically referenced by the build system.

Comment: How you added `FacebookGraphAPI` to your solution ? With separate project or you copied `.cs` file ?

Comment: I downloaded the FacebookGraphsAPI from [https://facebookgraphapi.codeplex.com/]  added `FacebookGraphAPI.dll` to my project

Comment: Try to copy `FacebookGraphAPI.cs` file to your project. I think there is mismatch between your application `System.Web` version and one that is using `FacebookGraphAPI.dll` .

Comment: Yes you are right I copied `FacebookGraphsAPI.cs` to my project and found that it uses `HttpClient` to communicate with Graphs API, this requires a ref. to `System.Net` namespace but `System.Net` is not available for WinRT apps. So I am trying to write alternate code.

Comment: @ShivkanwerSingh Ok, Is therey anything I can help? Or Question is closed ?

Comment: Thanks for your help.....for now I am trying to write some alternate code....will update the discussion once I get to some solution..

Comment: Classes in the System.Net namespace can be used to develop Windows Store apps or desktop apps. When used in a Windows Store app, classes in the System.Net namespace are affected by network isolation feature, part of the application security model used by the Windows Developer Preview. The appropriate network capabilities must be enabled in the app manifest for a Windows Store app for the system to allow network access by a Windows Store app.

Read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net(v=vs.110).aspx