# Not able to publish Azure Mobile App properly

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, azure-api-apps

I have implemented Azure Mobile App and Xamarin.Forms Client application. I want user to login using facebook from Phone and also want to fetch user's profile data. For this I have implemented the additional call/method into API controller in Azure Mobile App. I have followed steps and put the code as per your article but somehow get following error message when I run the Mobile App on localhost or trying to publish

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('') found multiple controllers defined with the same name but differing namespaces, which is not supported. The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers:
>
> Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Controllers.HomeController Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Controllers.HomeController

I understand this is related config settings. I have following code in place

```
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

    new MobileAppConfiguration()
                .UseDefaultConfiguration()
                .ApplyTo(config);

    app.UseWebApi(config);
    app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions
    {
        SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
        ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"] },
        ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"] },
        TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
    });
```

If I remove the default configuration from above then exception message go away but in that case I don't see the app getting hosted properly i.e. it is showing blank page in browser instead of ready page shown once app is hosted properly.

Answer (score 0):

What steps you followed, could you please show the link?
That exception is routing-related and very common, and can be fixed - for example, by use of areas. A lot of manuals are available, for example, here - http://blog.falafel.com/duplicate-controller-names-aspnet-mvc-areas/ .

Answer (score 0):

You have added two different SDKs - one for Azure Mobile Services v1 and the other for Azure App Service Mobile Apps (which can be considered v2).  You need to remove the reference to the older one.

Use the appropriate SDK for the service you are using, and delete the other one.

Comment: understand what you are trying to say. If I don't hv WindowAzure.MobileServices.Backend.? references then this problem won't occur. But if I don't add them, I won't get "ServiceUser" & without "ServiceUser" I can't find way to getprofile data for FB/Google.
I want to implement FB/Google login & fetch profile data. I get logged on User's token(I guess it's Azure AD token) but can't get profile data for FB/google using that token. So hv to cast user to ServiceUser & call "GetIdentitiesAsyn"

appreciate if any help is provided with above requirement in mind

Comment: Pls check the link according to which I'm trying to retrieve user profile data

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390377/get-user-info-like-name-email-id-etc-from-authentication-token-in-net-backend