# Error in getting user profile/detail using Xamarin android and azure facebook authentication

Tags: facebook, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I am using azure mobileservices facebook authentication and xamarin android native app. all configuration i have completed in facebook and azure and also add required permission "public_profile".

Facebook login page is displaying. after adding credential in facebook,I want userprofile from facebook,

But i am getting error "Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: (OAuthException - #1) Bad signature"

My code is

user = await client.LoginAsync(this, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);

userToken = user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken;

var fb = new FacebookClient();

fb.AccessToken = userToken;

dynamic me = fb.Get("me?fields=first_name,last_name"); **// I am getting error here**

string firstname = me.first_name;

Answer (score 2):

You are using the Azure Mobile Auth token to access Facebook.  You need to use a Facebook Access token.  There are two ways to do this:

1) Use a Facebook Client auth, then submit the facebook token to your azure mobile app to authenticate to the azure mobile app service.   This is documented as the "client-managed authentication" in the howto: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#authentication

2) DO a GET for https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me while setting the X-ZUMO-AUTH header to the value of userToken - this will return a JSON object that you can parse for the Facebook authentication.

In both cases you will have two access tokens - one for Azure Mobile Apps and one for Facebook.  You can then use the facebook token to access the facebook API for additional user information.

Comment: I want to do that in xamarin android native app. so your options are not useful for me. I have updated same in my question.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that.  Xamarin Android uses the .NET library (hence my reference to the documentation for .NET) and the PROCESS is the same irrespective of client.  Your code is clearly showing that you are using the token from Azure Mobile to access Facebook, which is what your underlying problem is.

Comment: I have solved using following link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390377/get-user-info-like-name-email-id-etc-from-authentication-token-in-net-backend

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var userInfo = await Client.InvokeApiAsync("/.auth/me", 
System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, null);
```